# Inverse Kinematics - saving, loading file and showing animation in BGE

Tags: animation, scripting, game-engine, export, import

I'm working on a application where I want to save animations as a script where I write only changes in positions.

something like :  L_Hand L_Arm -0.015 0.20 -0.18     (Start_of_Chain(dynamic) End_of_Chain(static) X Y Z)

and show it by inverse kinematics algorithm (something like CCD).

So questions is:

- Can I directly save the animation in some file format like my script?
  (because I haven't good view about all file the formats blender can export animations)
- Can I load that file and show animation in BGE application?

My main idea is about saving and loading animations not frame by frame, but 
only in script. Then show the animations in the BGE.

Answer (score 1):

Properties like

> L_Hand L_Arm -0.015 0.20 -0.18 (Start_of_Chain(dynamic) End_of_Chain(static) X Y Z)

could be easily described by XML or JSON. These data could be then dynamically read and applied to ["channels"](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/0.5/user/tips/armature_control.html). For correct use see current [Blender API](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/).